# How to append nested array without escaped quotation marks?

Tags: python, spacy

I need to setup training data for spacy. Spacy requires the data to be formatted in this way:

> TRAIN_DATA = [('very long text...', {'entities': [(48, 68, 'PRODUCT')]}),('very long text...', {'entities': [(36, 55, 'PRODUCT')]}),('very long text...', {'entities': [(0, 16, 'PRODUCT')]})]

I'm trying to extract this data automatically by using a regular expression to look for specific patterns on existing data.
This is my code to iterate over the data and to check if the regex pattern is met:

```
products = []
for index, row in rawdata.head(1000).iterrows():
    line = row['Activity.Description']
    if not (line is None):
        result = re.finditer(pattern, str(line), re.IGNORECASE)
        entities = []
        for match in result:
            train_tuple = (match.start(), match.end(), "PRODUCT")
            entities.append(train_tuple)
        if entities:
            products.append(f'("{line}", {{"entities": {entities}}})')
```

It works quite well to extract the data but for some reason the code adds an unwanted ' around the nested entities arry and ' around a dataset:

> TRAIN_DATA = ['("Followup for...", {"entities": ['(13, 22, "PRODUCT")']})', '("Brief discussion about ...", {"entities": ['(48, 60, "PRODUCT")']})']

How do I need to adapt my code to provide the output in the following format? - Removing the single quotation marks around each record (2nd char & the ' before the comma separating 2 records & removing the backslashes around the 'PRODUCT' label

> TRAIN_DATA = [("Followup for...", {"entities": [(13, 22, "PRODUCT")]}), ("Brief discussion about ...", {"entities": ['(48, 60, "PRODUCT")]})]]

I also tried utilizing a tuple but the backslashes moved from covering entities to covering the label (PRODUCT):

['("Followup for...", {"entities": [(13, 22, 'PRODUCT')]})

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: You are appending *a string* which is not what you indicated above. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
products.append(f'("{line}", {{"entities": {entities}}})')
```

you're building a string, but you probably want the actual data structure:

```
products.append((line, {"entities": entities}))
```

Comment: Hi fsimonjetz
thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately this is giving me:
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

and:

`products.append((line, {"entities": str(entities)}))`

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Comment: Why do you `str(entities)`?

Comment: When I just do `products.append((line, {"entities": entities}))` it's giving me  TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Comment: That kind of error usually occurs when you try to `join` a list of elements that contains non-string items. I highly doubt the `append` part is causing the error.

Comment: you are right - awesome it works - thank you very much